# my published composer package not installable

Tags: php, composer-php, packagist

I published a package on *packagist* and it is not installable.

```
$ composer --version
Composer version 1.10.15 2020-10-13 15:59:09

$ composer show --all mynamespace/mypackage
Warning from https://repo.packagist.org: Support for Composer 1 is deprecated and some packages will not be available. You should upgrade to Composer 2. See https://blog.packagist.com/deprecating-composer-1-support/

  [InvalidArgumentException]
  Package mynamespace/mypackage not found

$ (O4ADEV-357) composer require mynamespace/mypackage
Warning from https://repo.packagist.org: Support for Composer 1 is deprecated and some packages will not be available. You should upgrade to Composer 2. See https://blog.packagist.com/deprecating-composer-1-support/

  [InvalidArgumentException]
  Could not find a matching version of package mynamespace/mypackage. Check the package spelling, your version constraint and that the package is available in a stability which matches your minimum-stability (alpha).
```

I also see this warning on the packagist page for my package.

> This package is not installable via Composer 1.x, please make sure you upgrade to Composer 2+. Read more about our Composer 1.x deprecation policy.
> It seems to be due to the fact that my package does not support composer 1.

Is there a way to update my package so that it supports both Composer 1+ and Composer 2+?
Or is this not possible on packagist?

*Please note I have created a release of the package on github and can see the first version of my package is on the packagist homepage*
[image]

Comment: Metadata for Composer v1 is updated much less frequently (see dupe).  You can use v1  fine, but it will take much longer to be generally available, and it will depend on the package to be downloaded with some frequency.